# foreach loop quits after just adding three values c#

Tags: c#, datatable

I've this foreach loop which quits after three iterations. My data table is getting all the values but in the end nothing goes as planned.

Here is the code

```
foreach (DataRow item in dtEq.Rows)
{
    DataRow[] dr = dtData.Select("ManpowerId=" + item.ItemArray[(int)0] + "");

    if (dr.Length > 0)
    {
        foreach (DataRow drFound in dr)
        {
             item.BeginEdit();

             item[dtEq.Columns.IndexOf(drFound[2].ToString()) + 1] = drFound[3];
             item[dtEq.Columns.IndexOf(drFound[2].ToString()) + 2] = drFound[4];
             item.EndEdit();
        }
    }

}
```

[Here is the image](http://prntscr.com/alxvsa) that is returned

I ran the query using profiler, it runs perfect.

**Update**[DAL VALUE IS PERFECT](http://prntscr.com/aly5jm)

Comment: Check DataRow[] dr = dtData.Select("ManpowerId=" + item.ItemArray[(int)0] + "") is not 0 for the other rows ?

Comment: @JamesDev its 1 for first three and `{System.Data.DataRow[0]}` for last two

Comment: That should give you a clue to what the problem is.

Comment: @JamesDev As you can see in my update the DAL is return perfect values. can you please guide

Comment: "Strange" code. What's the point of `item.ItemArray[(int)0]`? Looks like each iteration will re-run same select. There are two `foreach`, which one exits after 3 iterations? Is such a complicated expression with multiple conversions necessary? `dtEq.Columns.IndexOf(drFound[2].ToString())`. Try to be more explicit, perhaps shorten the example, also produce an execution log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
item.ItemArray[(int)0]
```

Must be returning 4 and 5 respectively for the last 2 rows. You are then using this to query the other table http://prntscr.com/aly5jm where ManpowerId is 1002 and 1003 which is not finding the row.

Comment: Yes that was the issue their I'd missed the `Id` field so I added and it worked 
Thanks